# Отбор персонала по возрасту (sql-запрос)

Tags: sql-server, sql

Почему-то не срабатывает запрос:

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date) AS age FROM emploees WHERE age>17
```

Ругается, что age - недопустимое имя столбца. Без `WHERE` работает хорошо - выдает список возрастов.
Пробовал еще

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date) AS age FROM emploees) WHERE age>17
```

но тоже ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя накладывать условие на поле, которого еще нет.
Вы либо в условие введите определение поля, либо подзапрос сделайте.

Первый вариант:

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date) AS age FROM emploees WHERE YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date)> 17
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но почему-же этого столбца как бы нет, если мы его как бы определили с помощью AS? И двойной SELECt тоже не завелся.

Comment: Он появится после того, как запрос выполнится - появится с тем именем, с которым мы его определили. Т.е. если запрос будет в подзапросе, то к нему можно будет обращаться.
А пока он не может выполниться, потому что поле еще не существует.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Нет такого столбца `age`. Пишите:

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date) AS age FROM emploees WHERE (YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(born_date))>17
```